# ¿Como podria solucionar el siguiente error?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Text;    
using System.Data;    
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ClasesBase
{
    public class TrabajarPrestamo
    {   
        public static void AgregarUPrestamo(Prestamo oPrestamo)
        {
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ClasesBase.Properties.Settings.Default.conex);

            // comando de consulta
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Prestamo 
                             (PRE_Numero,
                              CLI_DNI,
                              DES_Codigo,
                              PER_Codigo,
                              PRE_Fecha,
                              PRE_Importe,
                              PRE_TasaInteres,
                              PRE_CantidadCoutas,
                              PRE_Estado) values 
                              (@n, @dn, @codD, @codP, @fechP, @imp, @ta, @cuo, @est)";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", oPrestamo.Pre_numero);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dn", oPrestamo.Cli_dni);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codD", oPrestamo.Des_codigo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codP", oPrestamo.Per_codigo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechP", oPrestamo.Pre_fecha);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imp", oPrestamo.Pre_importe);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ta", oPrestamo.Pre_tasaInteres);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuo", oPrestamo.Pre_cantidadCuotas);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@est", oPrestamo.Pre_estado);    

            cnn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Aqui da el error
            cnn.Close();
        }
```

El error es

> The parameterized query '(@n int,@dn nvarchar(4000),@codD int,@codP
>   int,@fechP datetime,@' expects the parameter '@dn', which was not
>   supplied.

Es un menu formulario del alta de prestamos. A continuacion les paso la clasebase llamada trabajarprestamos.

El error esta en la claseBase llamada trabajar prestamos en `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

Comment: El error hace referencia a que el parámetro **@dn**, no esta llegando a la query que deseas ejecutar. Puede que éste se encuentre nulo, así que te recomiendo que coloques un punto de interrupción en la línea donde le pasas el valor a tu query

Comment: En principio el codigo parece correcto y asignas al parameters @dn que menciona no estas asignando. Intentaste realizar un Rebuild de la solucion para ver si tomo el cambio

Comment: Estás seguro de que `oPrestamo.Cli_dni` no es nulo? intenta modificar esa linea a `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dn", oPrestamo.Cli_dni==null?DBNull.Value: oPrestamo.Cli_dni);`

Comment: Me sale el siguiente error cuando voy a reemplazar la linea de codigo
Error 1 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'string', tengo el proyecto en github, si queres o podes te lo paso: https://github.com/Lizzardds/Ademas

Comment: Si perdona, lo hice de memoria y hay un error,hay que hacer un cast a object de DBNull. Sería asi: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dn", oPrestamo.Cli_dni==null?(object)DBNull.Value: oPrestamo.Cli_dni);`

Comment: Hola, según el mensaje de error, en la tabla `Prestamo`, el tipo del campo `CLI_DNI` debe ser `nvarchar(4000)`. Verifica que el tipo de la propiedad `oPrestamo.Cli_dni` sea de tipo `String`

Answer (score 3):

El error indica que el valor del parámetro '@dn' no se recibió en el Query.

> expects the parameter '@dn', which was not supplied.

En realidad estas definiendo el valor faltante, y debes asegurar que `oPrestamo.Cli_dni` tenga valor definido.

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dn", oPrestamo.Cli_dni);
```

realiza un build de tu proyecto.

Comment: Ese es el tema, tiene valor definido, me sigue dando error, la verdad no se que sera

Comment: @Cpp realizaste un rebuild ?

Comment: Si, de la clasebase y de las vistas

Comment: Aqui esta el link, si podes respondeme por aqui.   
https://github.com/Lizzardds/Ademas

Comment: @Cpp en el método btnGuardarPrestamo_Click() agrega todos los valores al objeto oPrestamo antes de llamar   TrabajarPrestamo.AgregarUPrestamo(oPrestamo); falta por ejemplo agregar oPrestamo.Cli_dni

Answer (score -2):

Podrias verificar lo siguiente
 1. **oPrestamo.Cli_dni** es diferente de null
 2. el tipo de dato **oPrestamo.Cli_dni** es correcto al de la query
 3. Revisar si el objeto **oPrestamo** tiene definida esa propiedad **Cli_dni**